# com.esri.core.runtime.LicenseImpl.nativeIsClientIdValid(java.lang.String)

Tags: android, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime

I have problem with app crashing on start while invoking `ArcGISRuntime.setClientId(getString(R.string.ArcGISClientId));`

it causes exception:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean com.esri.core.runtime.LicenseImpl.nativeIsClientIdValid(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_esri_core_runtime_LicenseImpl_nativeIsClientIdValid and Java_com_esri_core_runtime_LicenseImpl_nativeIsClientIdValid__Ljava_lang_String_2)
at com.esri.core.runtime.LicenseImpl.nativeIsClientIdValid(Native Method)
at com.esri.core.runtime.LicenseImpl.b(SourceFile:103)
at com.esri.android.runtime.ArcGISRuntime$License.b(SourceFile:133)
at com.esri.android.runtime.ArcGISRuntime$License.a(SourceFile:72)
at com.esri.android.runtime.ArcGISRuntime.setClientId(SourceFile:51)
at com.ihs.connect.App.configureArcGIS(App.java:89)
at com.ihs.connect.App.onCreate(App.java:82)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1036)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6316)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Affected devices are running **Android 6.0 / 6.0.1**.
But it doesn't occur on all devices. Some of them are:

- SM-G920F (Samsung Galaxy S6)
- SC-02H (Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge)
- SM-N920C (samsung Galaxy Note 5)
- ASUS_Z010D (ASUS ZenFone Max)
- Nexus 5X (LG Nexus 5X)
- LG-H815 (LG G4)
- E5823 (Sony Xperia Z5 Compact)
- SAMSUNG-SM-G935A (Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge)
- SM-N9208 (Samsung Galaxy Note5 Duos)
- SGP771 (Sony Xperia Tablet Z4)
- 0PJA2 (HTC One M9)

I have tried running it with and without ProGuard, but still no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS Android Runtime are you using? 10.2.8?

Comment: I have been using 10.2.7, but switched also to 10.2.8 to check if it helps.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I posted my code on geo net

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: Lg Nexus 5x on 6.0.1

Comment: Could you download this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ihs.connect and tell if it crashes on start on your device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115992/discussion-between-fishman-and-alexander-n).